# How get Themes list via REST api?

Tags: themes, wp-admin, admin, api, rest-api

I wanted to get a list of all WordPress themes installed, together with their meta info (e.g. name, status, author etc) using WordPress REST api. I also wanted to be able to activate any theme via my API client.

I've gone through [this documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) but I didn't find any relevant end-point.

Is it possible at this moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own endpoint and use `wp_get_themes` to get a list of themes via that. Here is a simple one:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    //Path to rest endpoint
    register_rest_route( 'theme_API/v1', '/get_theme_list/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'theme_list_function' 
    ) );
});
// Our function to get the themes
function theme_list_function(){
    // Get a list of themes
    $list = wp_get_themes();
    // Return the value
    return $list;
}
```

Now you can get a list of your themes by accessing `http://example.com/wp-json/theme_API/v1/get_theme_list`.

I wouldn't suggest activating/deactivating themes via API. It can totally mess up things, such as activated widgets.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this code. Further, why activating theme via API will mess with other things, can you please elaborate? I'm trying to build a basic admin panel for WordPress via API.

Comment: For example, if your new theme doesn't support all the sidebars of your old theme, you will lose some of your widgets (deactivated actually). And some themes depends on specific plugins which demands activation of them too. And so many other stuff, that should be taken care of manually.

Comment: I don't think the issue of different themes having different sidebars, thus deactivation of some widgets on theme change is specific to REST api, is it?

Comment: I've tried the mentioned solution, it returns theme names but not the relevant meta info. The returned result is something like this: `{"backup":{"update":false},"theme1":{"update":false},"theme2":{"update":false} ... }`

Comment: `wp_get_themes` returns an array of `WP_Theme` class objects. You can create a `forearch` and save each of the metadata in an array, and then return the array. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Theme) is the documentation for the returned array.